# trigger individual segue for each tableview entity

Tags: swift, tableview, segue

I have a question regarding triggering an individual segue and storing user-generated data in each tableView entity(Patient). The Information, that I am adding is the same for each patient. But I have the problem, that the Information of one patient, is still visible for the others Patients as well.

import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class PatienIDViewController: UITableViewController {

```
let realm = try! Realm()



var itemArray: Results<Item>?







override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()




    //// Nicht vergessen

    loaditems()



    //            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



//Mark - TableView Datasource Methods
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemArray?.count ?? 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ToDoItemCell", for: indexPath)

    if  let item = itemArray?[indexPath.row] {

        cell.textLabel?.text = item.title

        // Ternary operator
        // value = condition ?

        cell.accessoryType = item.done ? .checkmark : .none

    }else{
        cell.textLabel?.text = "No Patients added"
    }

    return cell

}

//Mark - TableView - Delegate Methods
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath:
    IndexPath) {




    if let item = itemArray? [indexPath.row] {
        do{
            try realm.write {
                item.done = !item.done
            }
        }catch{
            print ("Error saving done Status, \(error)")
        }
    }

    tableView.reloadData()


    //        print(itemArray[indexPath.row])

    // Accessory


    //        context.delete(itemArray[indexPath.row])
    //        itemArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    //        itemArray[indexPath.row].done = !itemArray[indexPath.row].done


    //        save(item: Item)

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    // Hier könnte man einen Button einfügen
}




@IBAction func AddButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {




    var textField = UITextField()

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Patient", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Patient", style: .default) { (action) in
        // what will happen once the surgeon clicks the Add Patient Item


        let newItem = Item()


        newItem.title = textField.text!
        //            newItem.dateCreated = Date()
        newItem.done = false


        self.save(item: newItem)

    }

    alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
        alertTextField.placeholder = "Add New Patient iD"
        print(alertTextField.text!)
        textField = alertTextField
    }

    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}


func save (item: Item) {


    do {
        try realm.write {
            realm.add(item)
        }
    }catch{
        print ("Error saving context \(error)")
    }




    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

/// Read the Data
func loaditems() {

    itemArray = realm.objects(Item.self)


    tableView.reloadData()
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete{
        if let item = itemArray?[indexPath.row] {
            try! realm.write {
                realm.delete(item)
            }
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
        }
```

}

}

}

[Picture of the TableView, where the individual entities are stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHTQK.png)

Comment: I suggest updating your question with the code you use to: a) populate your table, b) show a new controller when a cell is clicked, c) populate the patient data into the new controller.

Answer (score 0):

The question as stated is somewhat vaguely worded. But I assume you have a list of `Patient`s displayed in a `PatientListViewController`, and when the user taps a table row you want to pass a single `Patient` to a `PatientDetailViewController`, and you want to do this by triggering a segue.

First, implement your UITableViewDelegate:

```
extension PatientListViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let patient = patient(at: indexPath) // Implement this in your class
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toPatientDetail", sender: patient)
  }
}
```

Then, send the individual Patient to the view controller:

```
class PatientListViewController: UIViewController {
  // ...
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    let destinationPatient = sender as! Patient
    let destination = segue.destination as! PatientDetailViewController
    destination.patient = destinationPatient
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I updated my question and added the code, where I want to implement the solution.

Comment: @Jonas I think rather than simply post more code you need to rephrase your question if my answer doesn't properly address it, or at least accept my answer if it does indeed address it. In any case, also please learn how to format code correctly on StackOveflow— thanks! :)